# Get position of an Object in my Array with RNPickerSelect - React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, select

I have a simple question,

```
<RNPickerSelect useNativeAndroidPickerStyle={false}
          onValueChange={(value) => this.setState({ action: value })}
          items={this.state.service.map(val => (
            {
               label: val.name,
               value: val.name
            }
            ))}
          placeholder={{
            label: 'Pick action...',
            value: 0,
          }}
        />
```

i have a `RNPickerSelect`. I would like to know if it's possible to know the position of the chosen Object.

Basically my items is like :

```
Array [
  Object {
    "name": "couscous",
  },
  Object {
    "name": "hello",
  },
]
```

And i want to know the position of the Object. Basically if it's the first Selected, i want 0, if it's the second, i want 1 etc...
Anyone know if it's possible to do that ?
The finality is to change the `value: val.name` on my items with `value: placeOntheList`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try updating items like:

```
items={this.state.service.map((val, i) => ({ label: val.name, value: i}) )}
```